# How to remove all characters after a 3-rd certain character in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have a string like `'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee'`.

How I can leave everything before the third underscore `_` using Redshift.

So in result I need to get `'aaa_bbb_ccc'`.

`aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee`  => `aaa_bbb_ccc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select regexp_substr(string, '^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd3124c348ae636b5027f8a7d22693e1) is a db<>fiddle.  This uses MySQL, because Postgres does not have `regexp_substr()` (it uses `regexp_match()`), but both Redshift and MySQL do.

Comment: A downvote on an answer *with* a Fiddle showing that it works.  Sigh.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff
Your solution works, thank you!

Comment: I have one more question. If I have words before or after 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee' separated by a space? How can I also remove them leaving only aaa_bbb_ccc? For example I have 'word aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee word '.

Comment: @Serge . . . That would be a different question.  If you cannot figure out how to adjust the regular expression (which might just be removing the initial `^`), then ask a *new* question.

Comment: thank you, I have figured out how to solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `split_part` for this

```
select split_part(txt,'_',1) ||'_'|| split_part(txt,'_',2)||'_'|| split_part(txt,'_',3)
```

A slight variation using `left` and `charindex`

```
select left(txt,charindex(split_part(txt,'_',4),txt)-2)
```

Comment: Looks like a serial downvoter.  Neither answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah it's weird